# Can you build a Windows 8 Live Tile that Launches A Website Instead of a Metro App?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

Live Tiles are the "front door" for metro apps on Windows 8.  Can you instead launch a website instead of a Metro app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you write an app that just does one thing, and that is to launch the browser with the specified Uri:

```
Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("http://my.website.com"));
```

That has the advantage that it is represented as a traditional app rather than a pinned site, so you can style the tile as you wish.

Comment: From my limited understanding, a tile launches a metro app.  So Tile -> Metro app.  What would happen to the Metro App if it launched a website. Could you then close the metro app automatically?

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing I could find is pinned sites or site tiles.
It doesn't look like you can customize the look and feel of these site tiles, but you can update them with notification counts.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/04/03/pinned-sites-in-windows-8.aspx